# How to render a nice conversation UI on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, controls, chat, xamarin

I'm writing an Android (Xamarin C#) application that will need to present a conversation/chat/texting-like UI (between two parties, but later with more).

I can't find a good 'chat' control that will offer the UI for me. Does one exist? Otherwise, does anyone have some stock xml that I can use in my app to render the UI?

Disclaimer: I'm a *very* new Android developer and am not familiar with all the UI concepts.

Answer (score 1):

All your need for a chat UI is just an EditText (`android.Widget.EditText`) and a Button (`android.widget.Button`). `EditText` has a rich functionality out of the box (things like typing text, selecting text, copying and pasting). The `Button` with a label 'Send' can be used to send the typed message and clear the contents of the `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more than a text box. I'm looking for balloons that represent previous messages (the kind where they come in from the left or the right depending on who said it).

Comment: You can achieve that by populating a ListView with baloons (which will be instances of TextView) and settin The ListView's stackFrom bottom property to true. You can do that from the xml layout with android:stackFromBottom property or from code with ListView.stackFromBottom() method.